# Project colaboration on a C# Project

Tags: c#, winforms, collaboration

a frend of mine and me are working on a C# project together. He's making a part and I'm making a part, but in his part he is calling one of my windows. Now, how do we put the work together in the best way? So we can work together at the same time on different screens

Comment: Use a software versioning and revision control system (like [SVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion))?

Comment: There are dozens of project colaboration projects both paid and free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are many tools to share project with team like [SVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) or team foundation server from Microsoft

Answer (score 2):

You should use any Source control system.

In your case, avoid Microsoft's product for source control system. Visual Source Safe is a mess, and is very dangerous. TFS is very heavy and complex to set up.

SVN is quite easy to set up on Windows, as [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) is free for simple scenarios.

[Git](http://git-scm.com/) can also be a good choice, because it supports a simple offline mode (actually this is the case because of the decentralized nature of Git), which can be useful.

Both SVN and Git have great tooling support on Windows + Visual Studio.

There may be many more protocol, but I use this two with success.

Answer (score 0):

SVN is a good start, but I'd rather recomend to look at [Team Foundation Services](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). In that case you don't event need to set up anything. Just sign up with Windows LiveId, and start using the SourceControl. It's integrated with Visual Studio and quite intuitive in use in my opinion. It requires an internet access though, while SVN can be installed and used in a local area network.